# iPhone SQLite questions - SELECT WHERE

Tags: iphone, sqlite, select, tableview

I got an application using SQLite to save data.
and 2 Field of Data, 1. Title, 2. Category.

For example, I saved 3 rows of Data

Title              Category

---

- Johnny's birthday      BIRTHDAY
- Meet Johnny         OTHER
- Mom's birthday      BIRTHDAY

---

I've already get all of these data and display on tableView,
Now when user wants to display data that belongs to "BIRTHDAY" category,
(which is "Johnny's birthday , Mom's birthday")

How to make this function? I know using SELECT WHERE.... 
but still can't figure out :(

---

I know how to write the SQL query to display only single data.

but I have multiple data's, so I'm searching for help to display multiple data..

PS. I'm using UIPickerView to let users choose Categories.

Comment: That link is not a tutorial, please update your post.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE category = "BIRTHDAY";
```

Comment: I'm sorry for that. I've removed it.
This tutorial is exaclly what I need http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2008/10/sqlite-tutorial-loading-data-as.html .

But I want to ask how to get multiple datas out of database, but not only single one (because this tutorial only gets single data out..)

Answer (score -1):

```
Select title, category from YOURTABLE where category= "BIRTHDAY"
```